# How to apply jQuery timeago or easydate on Backbone / Underscore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, template-engine

How do you apply [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) or [easydate](http://easydate.parshap.com/) on `<time class="prettydate"><%= created_at %></time>"` (which outputs something like this `Mon Jun 18 03:46:27 +0000 2012`)?

I tried the below but it doesn’t work because I am using Backbone / Underscore to render the date.

```js
$(function() {
  $('time.prettydate').easydate();
});
```

Here is my view:

```js
( function ( views ){

    views.ResultView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName : 'li',
        template: _.template($('#resultItemTemplate').html()),

        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
        },

        render : function () {
            //this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html($(html).timeago());
        }
    });

})( app.views );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you have something like this in a view:

```
render: function() {
    var html = _.template(...);
    this.$el.append(html);
    return this;
}
```

All you need to do is apply the plugin straight to `html` while you're appending it:

```
render: function() {
    var html = _.template(...);
    this.$el.append($(html).timeago());
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Fk6xF/

This works equally well if you're doing `this.$el.html(...)`.

If the pieces that you need to apply timeago to are *inside* your template, then you'll have to hunt them down and apply `.timeago()` to the individually. Something like this should do the trick:

```
render: function() {
    var html = _.template(...);
    this.$el.html(html);
    this.$el.find('.timeago').timeago(); // Assuming you're using class="timeago"
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dHr6D/

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I could not get it to work yet. Please see my edit above. Your demo works nicely. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Max: `var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON()); this.$el.html($(html).timeago());` should work, that's what my demo is doing.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, but I couldn't get it to work. I tried to create jsfiddle but it didn't function properly so I have ziped an example here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19974044/example.zip See the botton of index.html (for the backbone view JS code where the original method is commented out and replaced by your method). Nothing happens. I have a `<p>`as test for $.timeago and it works on that when applied on domReady with jQuery.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: @Max: What does `__metadata.media_etag.replace(/"/g,'')` end up as? I don't see `__metadata` anywhere so perhaps timeago can't parse that string as a time.

Comment: It ends up as `8/5/2011 5:05:32 PM` for the first item. See p.test at the top of the html page, which is `8/5/2011 5:05:32 PM` processed with `$('p.test').timeago();` resulting in `11 months ago`. In the template, it is located in: `<abbr class="timeago" title="<%= __metadata.media_etag.replace(/"/g,'') %>"><%= __metadata.media_etag.replace(/"/g,'') %></abbr>
`

Comment: That should work and does work with `p.test`. I didn't see any `__metadata` defined anywhere though, what happens if you use `'8/5/2011 5:05:32 PM'` in the template instead of `__metadata`?

Comment: @Max: You could also try `this.$el.timeago()` after you add the filled in template to `this.$el`.

Comment: Neither suggestion yielded anything (did not break or change anything). __metadata is part of JSON feed that is being interpreted: `http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/People(49446)/TitlesActedIn?&callback=callback&$top=3&$skip=0&$orderby=ReleaseYear&$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json&$callback=callback&$filter=&_=1340414050320` Don't we need to specify what element/class `$.timeago()` should apply to? I don't believe there is a default.

Comment: I tried `this.$el.html($(html).timeago($("abbr.timeago"))); this.$el.timeago($("abbr.timeago"))` with `$` and `jQuery` to specify the target and still nothing (no change).

Comment: I missed the obvious (of course) when I looked at your `example.zip`, have a look at my updated answer.